# Accessing published GAS web app from the url returns a blank page

Tags: google-apps-script

Thinking of creating a standalone app script, I created a google app script from Drive and places the codes in two files,Code.gs and ui.html, as follows:

> **Code.gs**

```
function doGet(e) {return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('ui');}
```

> **ui.html**

```
<html><h1>Hello World!</h1></html>
```

After this I went through the File > Manage Version and completed the steps there. Next I published the script and also got the web app url.
The problem is when I use this url in the browser I got only a blank page. There is however no problem when I use the link to test the latest code.
What is the problem here? Am I missing something or what?

Answer (score 1):

please double check your steps, eventually check that the published version is really what you show here, it **should** work !

I just tested it [here](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwcV7kSvV3KTmB1urtHj3BUbokg_PQztNrbfua37LRkcEFyER8/exec) using exactly your setup...

Comment: Hi Serge thanks for your response. Here's how the problem got solved.
Without changing any code, I clicked on "Manage Version" and created version 2. After this I re-published the app. But the same problem persist. In frustration I clicked "Disable web app" and re-publish again and lo! it works. So here's the catch perhaps **the app does not get published and updated automatically when an old copy of the exec is still present.** That's a bug isn't it? My first version did not work maybe because I had published without writting anything in ui.html.